# Azure Stream Analytics: When does a stream analytics job actually process data if the job query is a day wise TUMBLINGWINDOW?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

### Context

I have created a streaming job using Azure portal which aggregates data using a day wise TUMBLINGWINDOW. Have attached a code snippet below, modified from the docs, which shows similar logic.

```sql
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, -1, System.Timestamp()) AS WindowStart
    System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd, 
    TollId, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM Input TIMESTAMP BY EntryTime  
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(day, 1), TollId
```

### Question

If the TUMBLINGWINDOW outputs at the end of the window (***which in the case that I start my job at midnight of any given day would mean shortly after midnight of the next day***) then during the day is data still being processed or does the processing only happen based on when the query is outputting?

An explanation in detail as to how this would work would be great. Haven't found any documentation which really explains these concepts in detail (with these edge cases)

### Thoughts

I am trying to gauge how if I stop a job from running and start it again from "When Last Stopped" would it still lead to the same aggregation as if I'd left it on all the time (if it would then how)? Bearing in mind I am using a day wise TUMBLINGWINDOW?

Answer (score 1):

The output time of the tumbling window is absolute, and not dependent on the query start time. A daily tumbling window generates an output at 00:00:00AM, an hourly one every top of the hour (00:00:00AM, 01:00:00AM...), etc.

So here the job is waiting for 24h, loading patiently the data in memory, until it's 00:00AM so it can perform the computation and output the results. Then it starts waiting again.

Here, with a daily window, nothing prevents you from stopping the job from 00:01AM to 23:59PM.

(**EDIT - THIS IS NOT CORRECT - FIXED BELOW**) *Just be mindful that when you start it, the [start time option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/start-job#start-options) needs to cover the missing time (so either 'when last started' - because we checkpoint data - or custom time 24h before).*

(**CORRECTION**) Just be mindful that when you start it, the [start time option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/start-job#start-options) needs to cover the output window you want covered - ASA will reload all the necessary data even if it's before that time. What you drive with the start time is the output time, not the data input period.

As long as the data is still here (be mindful of the retention period of the event hub, by default 1 day), you could pause for an entire week, and have the job reprocess the whole period to emit 7 results. For that you just need a start time that covers the period.

Note that it takes time to re-ingest the whole dataset, and compute the operation on it. So if you absolutely need your daily average to be out at 00:00:00AM, then restart the job a few minutes prior so it can catch up. Else you will get that output at 00:00:10AM (or whatever the times it take to reload the data in memory).

Comment: [@Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633925/florian-eiden) Thanks this really does help! Just want to parrot a few ideas (_**let me know whether what I say is right or not**_). If I have a job running and I stop it at say `00:30AM` then all the data from midnight up until then (`00:00am-00:30am`) has already been "loaded into memory" and thus if I restart the job at `23:30pm` on the same day from "When last stopped" then it would just continue loading data into memory that has accumulated since the stop time? _**So the end output would be the same as if I'd left job on the whole day?**_

Comment: Also when you say "patiently loads data into memory" does that count as processing the records from event hub? Like during this process are the records no longer in the event hub if they get loaded into memory? (or is it like a copy of it).  Finally, the last point you made "whatever the times it takes to reload the data in memory" how could I gauge this better? Say I restart it 30mins prior at `23:30pm` in order to provide enough time for the daily catch up is there anything specific I could monitor to know that I have provided enough time for catch-up?

Comment: For the first comment, **yes**. If you look at the doc I linked: *"Azure Stream Analytics will automatically look back at the data in the input source. For instance, if you start a job “Now” and if your query uses a 5-minutes Tumbling Window, Azure Stream Analytics will seek data from 5 minutes ago in the input. The first possible output event would have a timestamp equal to or greater than the current time, and ASA guarantees that all input events that may logically contribute to the output has been accounted for"*. Let me edit my answer to make that clearer ;)

Comment: For the second question, **no**, we are not caching data across restarts. I understand how my phrasing suggested that and I will update that sentence, sorry for the confusion. We are re-reading the necessary data so it does need to be in the event hub.

Comment: Finally, there is not really a way to tell, as it depends on your data and query. You will need to try it out to find out ;)

Comment: Thanks again! Apologies I still feel slightly confused. You said "For the first comment, **_yes_**" where I describe how if the job is stopped and then I restart it from "**_when last stopped_**" it would continue accumulating events from the stop time (since data prior to that is already in memory. **_However_** you then say that data isn't cached across restarts so it reloads all of the prior data. Does that still imply (**_based on the scenario I described_**) that it reloads all of that data 1 day back from when last stopped and thus doesn't cache in that sense but in the end

Comment: **Continued:** would still have all data for that given day when it outputs at midnight of the same day since it would reload all of that same data back into memory (in particular `00:00 - 00:30`) when you restart from "**_when last stopped_**". Hence that would still be present during the aggregation?

Comment: My bad wording, sorry about that, but you are correct. When you stop the job, we dump all the current state. When you restart the job, you need to tell it from when you want it to output results. It will automatically go "back in time" to reload the data required for that. It's best to do "when last stopped" so you don't end up with duplicates in output. So yes, it will reload the data from 1 day back so that the daily aggregate is complete.

Comment: Ok thanks! (Still have 1 small doubt) So as a final confirmation if I have an already running job which is paused at `00:30` and I start it back up at `23:30` (1380min later same day) using when last stopped then it will reload 1 days back from `00:30` and output the events for the given day TUMBLINGWINDOW which include event timestamps within `00:00 - 00:30` since reloaded back into memory `00:30 - 23:30` since when last stopped includes timestamps after restart time and `23:30 - 00:00` since TUMBLINGWINDOW would output at midnight and we stop it at `00:30` on the next day?

Comment: This cycle would then repeat?

Comment: Yes, you got it. As long as the data is available in the input (be mindful of even hub max retention), then ASA will reload all the data from let's say `2022-01-02 00:00` to `2022-01-03 00:00`. Since you restarted it from last stopped, and you stopped it on `2022-01-02 00:30`, the next daily it will output is `2022-01-02` and not `2022-02-02`. It can only do that when the day ends, at `2022-02-03 00:00`, and at that time the entire day of data will be considered (`2022-01-02 00:00` to `2022-01-03 00:00`) independently of when that job was stopped.

Comment: If instead of `00:30`, you start the job 1 week later, as long as you use `from last time`, and you have the data still available in the input, then you will get all the 6 or 7 missing daily windows, each covering the 24 hours of each day.

Comment: Great, thanks! A small note, I think you meant `2022-01-03` instead of `2022-02-02` **_feel free to confirm_** (second comment above this one) but regardless I think I get your point now. You mentioned `from last time` is this the same as `when last stopped`?

Comment: You are right in both cases. This format is hard :D